# Custom AlertDialog display issue

Tags: android

I have created a custom dialog for my app. that when you click the button exit. it will prompt you an alertdialog. base on the tutorial on [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). I have created my own custom alertdialog. Just wanna ask why is my dialog looks so awful. like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qma3n.png).. yes and no confirmation button does now show how i was expecting it like the one in developers [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYTqi.png). as you can see the button sign and cancel looks great.

here is my code

```
exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
                LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater(); 
                builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirmation_game_restart, null)) 
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              //exit
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });      
               builder.create().show(); 


            }
        });
```

custom dialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFBB33"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="Exitting?"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="Are you sure you want to exit?"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: as you see on the second image. the dialog looks nice. I want to achieve that one.

Comment: "Looks nice" is vague. You need to be exact here. What is nice there? Borders, colours, what?

Comment: ok. on the second image. the confirmation buttons like `sign in` and `cancel` are different. On my custom alertdialog. the first image. the button `yes` and `no` are different. Second image uses flat ui while my alertdialog uses realistic

Comment: Ok now we're getting somewhere. To style a button http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Comment: builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirmation_game_restart, null)) replace builder.setView(R.layout.confirmation_game_restart)

Comment: @VM ..I see. so it was styled also. Thanks. I'll try that one.

Comment: @Sanket990..it doesn't work. I get an error on setView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the dialog on that d.android.com page uses Holo theme.
You could set it for your application, but note for android versions, that it will be used against: holo was implemented since 4.x+ android (API >= 14)

To set theme you can set this attribute in  tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`:
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"`
or (as IDE's love to pre-set during project creation):
`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` and then in styles.xml file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

That's an easy way if, for example, your minSdk version is 14 or more. Otherwise this will still look "awful" on older devices.